# gcc struggling with struct foo_v1 : foo_v2 { a; };

Tags: c, gcc

my gcc (9.1.0) struggle with following structure definition

```
struct foo_v1 : foo_v2 { a; };
```

i guess it could be a matter of coding version such as ansi or c99.

reading [9.4.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.4.0/gcc.pdf) i could not find <struct a : b { c; };> notation.

please could anyone give me a hint where to find standard defining such a notation or how to compile with gcc.

have a great day

Comment: You sure this is C?  It looks like struct inheritance in another language.

Comment: yes, i'm pretty sure. there is #include <stdint.h>, regular #define .. and #if __cplusplus. but i do not know which process does interpret it.

Comment: Sooo why don't you post exactly where did you found it? What library? What file? Which line? `which process does interpret it` what process is there to choose from? What is it interpreting? In what way? Note that you _did not_ ask what does that line means or what it does - you specifically asked how to compile it with gcc.

Comment: @SwissGeorge If the code contains `#if __cplusplus.`, then it is likely that any code guarded by that `if` is supposed to be C++, not C, but as mentioned in the answer `a;` as member without some macro expanding that is not correct syntax in either C or C++.

Comment: The compiler manual is not the right document to learn C. You should consider getting a book about C or looking into a C [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: i found such structure definitions in bootimg.h see [LineageOS](https://github.com/groessler/abootimg/blob/master/bootimg.h) and [android](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/mkbootimg/) as examples.

Answer (score 3):

> how to compile with gcc.

It is not valid C syntax. It is not possible to compile it with `gcc` as a C source code. It is also not a common extension in common C compilers.

---

It may be possible to compile the following with a C++ compiler (which makes the line compile-able after adding two lines and adding `-xc++` to `gcc`):

```
struct foo_v2 { int stuff; };
#define a  int variable
struct foo_v1 : foo_v2 { a; };
```

The presented line in the question, on its own, is not valid C++ code anyway.